# Why won't regular CDs play on my Windows 7 system?

Tags: windows-7, audio, windows-media-player, codec, compact-disc

I've got some regular CDs that I cannot get to play on my Windows 7 (64 bit) system.  When I try to play them I get the message:

***"Windows Media Player cannot play the file.  The Player might not support the file type or might not support the codec that was used to compress the file."***

This is a relatively new system so I've never tried playing CDs on it before.  Do I need to load a specific codec to play CDs?  I would think Windows would play CDs out of the box.

Comment: What are these regular CDs? Are they actually video or audio CDs, or just data discs? Can you open them from (My) Computer?

Comment: @Om Nom Nom - I would guess that they are audio CDs from the [audio] tag the OP used.

Comment: "I would think Windows would play CDs out of the box."

It should

Comment: Could it be your CD/DVD Rom is going bad? Does it play any other optical media?

Comment: They are audio CDs.  Music CDs, Like you would buy from the store.  Standard commercial, published, CDs containing signed artists, the Beatles, 50 Cent, Lady GaGa, that sort of CD

Comment: Other media (DVDs) play fine.  The system is new...less than a month old.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WMP comes with pre-installed codecs which have never satisfied me. You should install a codec pack and try again. I personally recommend [CCCP Codec Pack](http://www.cccp-project.net/).

Comment: Installing a codec pack to play a regular audio CD is crazy.

Comment: Believe it or not.  This seems to have solved the problem.

Comment: My new Windows 7 box wouldn't recognize audio or MP3 CDs in either of my two drives (one internal, one external (even though I was already burning DVDs with external drive). The iTunes diagnostic reported "unable to access audio cd." But I installed CCCP and all is as it should be. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you scanned the system for malware lately?

You can run System File Checker (SFC), see if it replaces any missing or corrupted system files

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929833

.