# Audio CDs Won't Play In WMP 11 In Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, audio, codec

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why won’t regular CDs play on my Windows  7 system?](https://superuser.com/questions/158162/why-wont-regular-cds-play-on-my-windows-7-system)

I've got some regular audio CDs that I cannot get to play on my Windows 7 (64 bit) system. When I try to play them on WMP 11, I get the message:

"Windows Media Player cannot play the file. The Player might not support the file type or might not support the codec that was used to compress the file."

This is a relatively new system so I've never tried playing CDs on it before. Do I need to load a specific codec to play CDs? I would think Windows would play CDs out of the box.

Comment: exact duplicate of your previous post: [Why won't regular CDs play on my Windows  7 system?](http://superuser.com/questions/158162/why-wont-regular-cds-play-on-my-windows-7-system)

Comment: please don't repost questions.  if you need to add information, you can edit your original post (use the gray "edit" link).